# Does the landing distance required for a wet runway needs to be within a certain range of the landing distance available?

Tags: landing, aircraft-performance, runways, easa-regulations, runway-contamination

Conform the regulations the landing distance required (LDR) for propeller engine aircraft needs to be within 70% of the landing distance available (LDA). The LDR for a wet runway needs to be multiplied by 1,15 (115% LDR). I was wondering whether this 'wet LDR' also needs to be within the 70% of the LDA to meet the regulations, or does it only need to be within the total LDA? 
And does the same count for contaminated runways?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer = Yes.

Long Answer = landing within 70% of the LDA rule is a HARD limitation. The runway's length does not change with the weather, so the 70% cannot be changed. But, of course, your A/C landing distance **does** change with weather. Thus, your 115% landing distance required must still be within the 70% LDA.

in practical application, not every landing you do will use 70% of the LDA, or even close to it (It's only a limitation, right?). In many cases, There's still lots of room for your 115% LDR to land safely within the 70% LDA.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi James!  Welcome to our site.  Do you have any references (to regulations perhaps) which backup what you are saying here?  We like to provide definitive answers with sources when possible.  Also, just in case you missed it, JP93 tagged his question as an "EASA-REGULATIONS" question, so is specifically asking about EASA and not FAA rules (which are possibly the same, but when citing references, it's an important distinction!).